# How do I find this element for this sign in button using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a newbie trying to follow a Selenium Python tutorial and I need to know how to find the element for the sign in button on a website. The tutorial just used find_element_by_id but the website I am trying is different.
Code from inspect:
`<button class="button m-margin-top text-inherit" type="submit" data-automation-id="signin-submit-btn">Sign in</button>`

Comment: is my answer working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath`

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign in"]')
```

Or more specific approach by including button class in xpath

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='button m-margin-top text-inherit'][.='Sign in']")
```

Answer (score 0):

right click the element and copy its XPATH

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"")
driver.get(your url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('paste xpath here')
```

this may help you :D